# Como solucionar erro de tipos incompatíveis no vba?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou tentando percorrer uma lista de resultados filtrados no VBA e encontrei a seguinte sintaxe, contudo ao executar aparece "Tipos incompatíveis"

```
loc13 = Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").AutoFilter.Range.Columns(17).Rows(j).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
Debug.Print (loc13)
```

Comment: Salve, meu caro! Eu diria que você está usando o ```AutoFilter``` errado... Você poderia dizer o que você pretende colocar na variável ```loc13```? Ademais, qual é o tipo da variável e o que aparece se você colocar um ```Debug.Print Workbooks("Histórico 2013-2021.xlsx").Worksheets("Memória Intervenções").AutoFilter.Range.Columns(17).Rows(j).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address```?

Comment: Na variável loc13 eu pretendo colocar o valor filtrado e percorrer com um FOR. Ao debugar esta linha de código, o mesmo me retorna a primeiro valor visível (que era o esperado), contudo ao continuar o for, ele não atualiza os valores das próximas linhas. Apenas me retorna o primeiro valor